# Can I run my app on my device without a paired Apple Watch from XCode, even if it has an Apple Watch target?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I've added an Apple Watch target to my app and now it will only run in the simulator. I've written the code in Swift and it ran fine; once adding the Apple Watch target, I get a message that it cannot run on my iOS device because it does not have a paired Apple Watch.

Comment: Which target are you trying to run?  Make sure you have selected the app and not the watch app in the top bar of Xcode

Comment: Doh! That was the issue! Thanks! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which target are you trying to run? Make sure you have selected the app and not the watch app in the top bar of Xcode